# Inserting into database via web form - where am I going wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to teach myself PHP, and it's going well, but I'm a bit stuck on this.

I've got a plain old HTML page with this:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
id: <input type="text" name="id" /><br><br>
Firstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br>

<input type="submit" />
```

On insert.php, I have this:

```
  $data = array('id' => $_POST['id'],
    'firstName' => $_POST['fname'],
    'lastName' => $_POST['lname'],
  );

  $sql = "INSERT INTO test(id, firstName, lastName) values(:id, :firstName, :lastName)";

  $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

  $statement->execute($data);
```

I haven't posted the code from my connection, since the problem doesn't seem to lie there; I've tested it by echoing some info from the database, and it works fine. Except, when I add the above code, it doesn't echo anything. I remove all the code above and it works again.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably getting a fatal error for some reason. Try check the error log files

Comment: `id` is not auto incrementing?

Comment: By the way you forgot to close the `</form>`

Comment: You aren't echoing anything I can see here.

Comment: On your insert.php file, just below where you define $sql add: var_dump($sql, $_POST);  let me know what you get from your page response.